# Rust function which mutates self and then returns an immutable reference, borrow checker says self is still borrowed mutably

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a function that I would like to mutate `self` and then return an immutable reference into `self`. In theory, I would think that the borrow checker could reason that the mutable reference only lives as long as the function body, and so from when the function exits to when it's return value is dropped `self` is only borrowed immutably. However, the compiler is telling me that `self` is borrowed mutably for the lifetime of the return value. Here's an example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(i32);

impl Foo {
    fn doo(&mut self) -> &Self {
        self.0 += 1;
        self // implicit coercion
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo(0);
    let bar = foo.doo();
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", &foo, bar);
}
```

In theory I think this could work since `&foo` and `bar` are both `&Foo`s so they can coexist, but this give the error message:

```rust
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `foo` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:14:28
   |
13 |     let bar = foo.doo();
   |               --------- mutable borrow occurs here
14 |     println!("{:?}, {:?}", &foo, bar);
   |                            ^^^^  --- mutable borrow later used here
   |                            |
   |                            immutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

So is there a reason why the return value of `doo` must continue to borrow `self` mutably, or is there a way to get the behavior I want?

Comment: This seems a little XY problem-y. Can you give a use case that demonstrates why/when this would be useful?

Comment: It's not possible to borrow mutably a var twice. `foo` and `bar` references are the same. Replace `bar` with `foo` will work. `let foo = foo.doo()`

Comment: See also the ['nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-mismatch.html) for a discussion of why this doesn't work in Rust.

Comment: @isaactfa, thank you, that exactly answers my question. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

[Lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html) comes into play here.  The first step to understanding what's happening is to desugar this and make the lifetimes on the `Foo::doo` method explicit:

```
fn doo<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a Self
```

From this signature, we can see that the lifetime of the returned reference is the same as the lifetime of the input reference.  This means that the returned immutable reference *extends the mutable borrow.*  Rust doesn't have any kind of reference-downgrading mechanism; `foo` will be considered mutably borrowed as long as the `bar` reference is alive.

Answer (score 0):

While this should compile, Rust's lifetime system sadly can't figure this situation out (yet(?)). We can turn to the ['nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-mismatch.html#limits-of-lifetimes) to learn why.

As @cdhowie rightly points out, explicitly annotating the lifetimes for `doo`, we get

```
impl Foo {
    fn doo<'a>(&'a mut self) -> &'a Self {
        self.0 += 1;
        &/* 'a */*self
    }
}
```

And when we similarly annotate the rest of the program like this

```
fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo(0);
    let bar: &/* 'mutable_borrow */Foo = Foo::doo(&/* 'mutable_borrow */mut foo);
    let baz: &/* 'immutable_borrow */Foo = &/* 'immutable_borrow */foo;
    println!("{:?}", bar); // => 'mutable_borrow: 'immutable_borrow 
}
```

we can see why the borrow checker doesn't think this is valid. In its eyes, `bar` can live only as long as the mutable reference to `foo` we pass in. Or rather, for as long as `bar` lives, that mutable reference has to live. And we can't get a shared reference while a mutable one is still alive.

P.s.: I don't know enough about Polonius to know whether that could compile this, I'd love to hear from someone who does.